# Can Android use standard built JAR files?

Tags: android, unit-testing, java

Im pretty sure the answer is no, but im using the new IntelliJ EAP version and have a project i worked on a while back which was just written against JDK 1.6 for an applet based application.

However now i could see how it could be useful in an android app that im interested in creating.

Do i now have to re-write all the code/tests again targeting the android sdk or can i just drop in my existing JAR file and only use android for the UI layer.

Its just android seems to make testing WAY harder than it needs to be, and i have alot of existing tests written and working, if it wasnt so hard to just write a quick unit test (standard Junit @Test style) i wouldnt mind porting, however i just dont get the whole instrumentation thing, as i dont need a UI at the moment...

Anyway so back to the point, can i use my existing JDK built code in an android app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No!

Android uses the "Dalvik" VM from project harmony which uses a different set of bytecodes which are incompatable with the standard Java JVM bytecodes.

This was done both to optimise the VM for opreration on mobile platforms, and, probably more importantly to try and avoid Copyright and patent disputes with Sun and now Oracle.

More info  [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dalvik_%28software%29)

However there is a tool called "dx" which can perform the conversion in the dev environment.

Comment: Thought as much... I was just hoping there was an *easier* way to develop for android in a test driven approach as pure unit testing seems almost impossible at the moment...

Answer (score 2):

Okay, let me clear up your confusion.

Jars are converted to dex Dalvik bytecode during the compiling process thus you can use 3rd party jar libs.

However, in your case because its applet which has a different application lifecycle yes you might have to re-do it to get it to work in android.

As far as testing instrumentation is used on all java mobile development even JavaMe. It basically means that the Junit tests are run in the emulator or device but in android's case you are using android mock objects to test android specific things.

Comment: I wouldnt be using the applet part, i would only be using the functionality within a library (JAR) that was used by the applet.

Comment: yes but the applet part will probably not compile as it relies on a javaSe part that android does not use.

Comment: Sorry i think im confusing matters, there may as well be 2 seperate JAR files. One contains standard Java code/objects, its all basically simple models and logic. There is then another JAR which uses this one and opens as an applet. I would only be wanting to take the first JAR over as to my knowledge Android supports everything that is being used in that code, its just in a JDK 1.6 JAR... Either way i still think that the answer is no...